# Javascript object property logs normally but is undefined?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a Javascript object that gets initialised in an asynchronous manner, later edited and then stored in an array until it can be saved. The problem is that one of the checks it goes through is `_.has(obj, 'Id')`. This test always fails. I've used `JSON.stringify()` to log the object's internals and everything has its value and looks correct. When I run a simple test of this line with hard-coded values in plunker, everything works as expected. I've tried accessing the Id values through `obj.Id` and `obj['Id']` but these both return undefined and I don't know why. Why can `stringify` read the property but a regular accessor can't? The Id is a value that is not touched between initialisation and saving of the object.

Comment: Providing the code you're working with would help.

Comment: Maybe the object isn't yet received because you are loading it in an asynchronous manner and probably are not working with callbacks?

Comment: can u post a snippet for better understanding